# Unexpected result when combining IFNULL with TRUNCATE

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query returns 0.000 when I expected it to return 0.

```
SELECT IFNULL(TRUNCATE(NULL, 3), 0) FROM DUAL
```

Why is that?

Breaking it apart works as expected and described in the [TRUNCATE function documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) and [IFNULL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) :

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(NULL, 3) FROM DUAL
```

returns null.

```
SELECT IFNULL(null, 0) FROM DUAL
```

this returns 0. So why do I get 0.000 when nesting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `TRUNCATE(NULL,n)` is `DOUBLE`. This can be seen by running `mysql` with the `--column-type` parameter:

```
$mysql -u root --column-type testdb

mysql> SELECT(TRUNCATE(NULL,3));
Field   1:  `(TRUNCATE(NULL,3))`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       DOUBLE
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     20
Max_length: 0
Decimals:   3
Flags:      BINARY NUM 


+--------------------+
| (TRUNCATE(NULL,3)) |
+--------------------+
|               NULL |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

According to the [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) documentation page:

> The default result value of IFNULL(expr1,expr2) is the more **“general”** of the two expressions, **in the order STRING, REAL, or INTEGER**

Therefore your result is `0.000`, the 0 as DOUBLE truncated to 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is wrong.  `TRUNCATE(NULL, 3)` is going to return a decimal value with three decimal places.  Although the value is `NULL`, `NULL` has a type associated with it.  The type is integer by default.  But this is not a default situation.

So, `0` is converted to a decimal with three decimal places.

EDIT:

To understand what I mean, consider this code:

```
create table t as
    select truncate(NULL, 3) as x;

describe t;
```

You will see that the column has a precision of "3".  The `NULL` value is not typeless.  You can see this on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ff4d5/3).

Comment: Looks plausible. Any sources? Couldn't find anything closer than "Returns the number X, truncated to D decimal places"  which seems a bit of a stretch for this case.

Comment: `select truncate(null,3)` gives `NULL`, not a decimal value with three decimal places. What would you expect `select ifnull(truncate(null,3),4)` to return?

Comment: I was sort of asking @gordon-linoff. By the way, `ifnull(truncate(cast(null as unsigned),3),0)` does what you expect. But I still don't understand how the type of something inside the truncate function affects the result of `ifnull`

Comment: Even `select cast(ifnull(truncate(null,3),0) as decimal)` does what you would expect. The type of the output without any casting is `double`, so I'm not sure how the `cast` affects it.

Comment: @ChrisLear . . . You are misunderstanding.  NULL is not NULL is not NULL.  It has a type associated with it, and that is what the `truncate()` is doing -- returning `NULL` with a type.  If you insert the value into a table, then this is obvious.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sure it's true that I am misunderstanding, and I would very much like to understand.
But I still don't, and not through lack of trying. If `truncate(null,3)` gives something that looks like null but has a type (double), then it's still not at all obvious why `ifnull([double null].0) shows 0.000. Especially when, if you cast it as decimal, it gives 0 (not 0.000).
Also, try this: `set @a:=truncate(null,3); select ifnull(@a,0);`. You get 0, not 0.000.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting error. I'm not allowed to edit it now.

Comment: OK, having re-read the edited answer, I think I see now. The type of `truncate(null,3)` is `double(20,3)`, whereas the type of @a when I do `set @a:=truncate(null,3)` is just `double` (no precision). I was using the second example when I was trying to work out what was going on, hence the majority of the confusion.